# greasemonkey script to replace a a letter in the url

Tags: url-rewriting, greasemonkey

I tried to modify some scripts I found - but they're not working.

When there is a link on a loaded page that points to: 
`https://website.new/ia-o/number1/number2/number3/number4.jpeg.html`

I want it to actually point to:
`https://website.new/ib-o/number1/number2/number3/number4.jpeg.html`

So basically just replace one letter in the link (from `*/ia-o/*` to `*/ib-o/*`)

This is the script that I have tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        website.new
// @namespace   lii
// @description redirect to anothersite
// @include     https://website.new/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);

for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

    thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace('https://website.new/ia-o/',
                                          'https://website.new/ib-o/');

}
```

But it doesn't do anything.

If anyone can help - I'd greatly appreciate it!

Part2:
Even better solution would be if I could remake the whole link like this.

Old link on a web page : `https://website.new/ia-o/number1/number2/number3/number4.jpeg.html`

New link on a page: `https://website.new/o/number1/number2/number3/number4.jpeg`

(so remove the ia- and also .html from the link)

But either solution would work!

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to redirect to the other URL, or just replace the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace href attribute in all links found in current page

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        website.new
// @namespace   lii
// @description redirect to anothersite
// @include     https://website.new/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    for (var i=0,link; (link=document.links[i]); i++) {
        link.href = link.href.replace('oldvalue', 'newvalue');
    }

})();
```

you can replace single letters

```
link.href.replace('a', 'o');
```

or whole words

```
link.href.replace('grease', 'tamper');
```

in your specific case, just remove the strings you don't want by replacing them with an empty string

```
link.href = link.href.replace(/ia-|\.html/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the previous reply, just made a bit shorter

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        website.new
// @namespace   lii
// @description redirect to anothersite
// @include     https://website.new/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

[...document.links].forEach(item => item.href = item.href.replace('oldvalue', 'newvalue'));
```